# I don't know what's wrong with this code I'm running on Just BASIC

Tags: basic

```
[Start]
n=INT((RND*10)+1)
PRINT "I have thought of a number."
PRINT "Try to guess it!"
PRINT "Enter your guess."
INPUT g

[Right]
IF g=n THEN GOTO [Finish]
**IF g < n PRINT "Your guess was wrong. Try again. The correct answer was "; n;"." THEN GOTO [Start]
IF g > n PRINT "Your guess was wrong. Try again! The correct answer was "; n;"." THEN GOTO [Start]**

[Finish]
PRINT "Well done! You guessed it."
END
```

Comment: I didn't use BASIC this century, but I think your use of `THEN` is incorrect.

Comment: I havent got a clue but im having a laugh trying to figure it out with this online compiler http://www.onlinecompiler.net/basic. If i get anywhere i'll let you know (dont hold your breath though)

Comment: What language is this? I am sure it isn't BASIC, as there is "PRINT". May be I can help you, if you will say what language it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF condition THEN positive ELSE negative
```

However, this

```
IF g > n THEN PRINT "Your guess was wrong. Try again! The correct answer was "; n;"."; GOTO [Start]
```

Won't do what you want because the IF...THEN...ELSE sentence ends after the print and subsequent GOTO will run in either case.

In most BASICs, you can do this:

```
IF g > n THEN 
  PRINT "Your guess was wrong. Try again! The correct answer was "; n;"."; 
ELSE
  GOTO Start
END IF
```

But I'm not sure about your particular flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Although it could be wrutten with less GOTOs, this should work too:

```
[Start]
n=INT((RND*10)+1)
PRINT "I have thought of a number."
PRINT "Try to guess it!"
PRINT "Enter your guess."
INPUT g

[Right]
IF g=n THEN GOTO [Finish]

PRINT "Your guess was wrong. Try again. The correct answer was "; n;"."     
GOTO [Start]

[Finish]
PRINT "Well done! You guessed it."
END
```